# how Update config.deploy visual Studio C#

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, app-config

I publish project in VS2010, in app.config I have string there.
There is any way I change connection string in Config.deploy for install new PC.

Because for new PC require change connection string there.

Comment: You should search for app.config transformation. you can have different configurations for different symbols, Debug, Release, Deploy, etc....

Comment: Is this windows application? if so, You can find File Type[Config] in installed path. Just right click on file and open with note pad or text editor. And then change connection string.